Sending transaction using Jupiter integerated terminal
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Jupiter Terminal</title>
    <script src="https://terminal.jup.ag/main-v2.js" data-preload></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (e) => {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
          window.Jupiter.init({
            endpoint: 'https://solana-devnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/6PikEvTwikjWfTn-g75R9R9tWx5CiRcZ',
            formProps: {
              initialSlippageBps: 1234,
            },
            useUserSlippage: false,
          });
        }
      });
    </script>

    
  </body>
</html>

. And this is the consistent error that i have been getting index.mjs:8899 Error: failed to simulate transaction: invalid transaction: Transaction loads an address table account that doesn't exist
at so.simulateTransaction (index.browser.esm.js:7056:15)
at async gs (optimist.esm.js:236:12)
at async index.mjs:8842:17
